# What is the use of StateMachineAttribute in .NET?

Tags: .net, state-machine

I came across a class called `StateMachineAttribute` in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.statemachineattribute?view=netframework-4.8). What is the purpose of `StateMachine` in .NET and what `StateMachineAttribute` is used for?

Comment: It is the base class for [AsyncStateMachine] and [IteratorStateMachine], the ones that the compiler actually emits on auto-generated methods.  Corresponds to the `async` and `yield` keywords, the compiler breaks up a method with those keywords and uses a logical state machine to figure out which part needs to be called.  Nothing very dramatic, just an int variable to keep track of progress.  Use a not-so-good decompiler to look at the generated code.  The attributes don't do anything special, just a cue to reflection tools/code.

Answer (score 1):

When you implement async method, C# compiler generate method with AsyncStateMachineAttribute that is derived from StateMachineAttribute

**C# code**

```
...
public async Task HelloWorldAsync()
{
        await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("Hello World!");
}
...
```

"Real" method (generated by compiler)

```
[AsyncStateMachine(typeof(<HelloWorldAsync>d__4))]
[DebuggerStepThrough]
public Task HelloWorldAsync()
{
    <HelloWorldAsync>d__4 stateMachine = new <HelloWorldAsync>d__4();
    stateMachine.<>4__this = this;
    stateMachine.<>t__builder = AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Create();
    stateMachine.<>1__state = -1;
    AsyncTaskMethodBuilder <>t__builder = stateMachine.<>t__builder;
    <>t__builder.Start(ref stateMachine);
    return stateMachine.<>t__builder.Task;
}
```

Really StateMachineAttribute isn't used by compiler. For methods that are state machine methods, the compiler will apply the AsyncStateMachineAttribute or IteratorStateMachineAttribute